# Como filtrar un dataframe en python por condicion de columnas

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente dataframe (hist_df), time(string), position_id(int), comment(string):

```
                  time  position_id      comment
0  2023-03-13 18:27:47    298804149             
1  2023-03-13 19:24:12    298803989  CT298803988
2  2023-03-13 21:40:35    298839667             
3  2023-03-13 21:42:00    298839901             
4  2023-03-13 23:42:00    298847712             
5  2023-03-13 23:45:11    298847774             
6  2023-03-14 02:01:55    298839670  CT298839667
7  2023-03-14 02:01:55    298839903  CT298839901
8  2023-03-14 02:17:10    298847775  CT298847770
9  2023-03-14 02:30:32    298847714  
10 2023-03-14 10:19:23    298815865  CT298803990
```

Me gustaría filtrarlo de la siguiente forma:
que los números que están después de de CT, por ejemplo el indice 1, sería 298803988, no se encuentra dentro de la columna position_id, esa sería la condición y también que la columna comment este vacía, el resultado sería el siguiente:

```
                  time  position_id      comment
0  2023-03-13 18:27:47    298804149             
1  2023-03-13 19:24:12    298803989  CT298803988
2  2023-03-13 21:40:35    298839667             
3  2023-03-13 21:42:00    298839901             
4  2023-03-13 23:42:00    298847712             
5  2023-03-13 23:45:11    298847774             
8  2023-03-14 02:17:10    298847775  CT298847770
9  2023-03-14 02:30:32    298847714  
10 2023-03-14 10:19:23    298815865  CT298803990
```

Los comment no están dentro de position_id y los vacíos en comment.

```
intente ésto pero no me funcion, me arroja todos nuevamente:
# Agregue éste valor para que no me diera error el apply lambda, pero si se puede evitar mejor.
hist_df.loc[hist_df["comment"]=='',"comment"]='CT0'
# Busca dentro de una columna
hist_df=hist_df[hist_df.apply(lambda r: int(r.comment[2:]) != r.position_id or r.comment=='CT0', axis=1)]
hist_df.loc[hist_df["comment"]=='CT0',"comment"]=''
print(hist_df)
```

Agradecería de antemano el apoyo, gracias.

Comment: Buen día, tal como está redactada la pregunta no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, ¿Deseas obtener todos las filas donde el comentario esté vacío junto con las filas donde el número después de CT escrito en el comentario no coincida con `position_id`? Es decir, en tu ejemplo ¿Debería devolver todas las filas?

Comment: Si mira todos los que estén vacios y también todos los que no tengan los números de comment en position_id, en este caso en el resultado están todos los vacíos y CT298803988, CT298847770, CT298803990  esos no están en ningún ticket, pero CT298803990 esta en el índice 2  y CT298839901 ésta en el índice 3 por eso se excluyen del resultado.